# making alarm manager repeat daily with time picker

Tags: java, android, eclipse, alarmmanager, timepicker

i'm trying to make my alarm manager repeat daily at the time chosen by the timepicker, i'm still new to java coding and stuff and i have no idea what to write inside the setRepeating() and in one alarm manager example i found this code

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

i tried changing it but i get an error 
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent) in the type AlarmManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, long, PendingIntent)

help?

```
public class AndroidTimeActivity extends Activity {

    TimePicker myTimePicker;
    Button buttonstartSetDialog;
    Button buttonCancelAlarm;
    TextView textAlarmPrompt;

    TimePicker timePicker;
    CheckBox optRepeat;

    final static int RQS_1 = 1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.picker);
        optRepeat = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.optrepeat);
        textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);

        buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
        buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

                calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                    //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                    calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                }

                setAlarm(calSet, optRepeat.isChecked());

            }});

        buttonCancelAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        buttonCancelAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                cancelAlarm();
            }});

    }

    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal, boolean repeat){

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        if(repeat){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                    targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), 
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    pendingIntent);

            textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                    "\n\n***\n"
                    + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                    + "Repeat\n"
                    + "***\n");
        }else{
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                    targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),  
                    pendingIntent);

            textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                    "\n\n***\n"
                    + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                    + "One shot\n"
                    + "***\n");
        }

    }

    private void cancelAlarm(){

        textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                "\n\n***\n"
                + "Alarm Cancelled! \n"
                + "***\n");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

What you're missing in `setRepeating` is that there's 4 parameters you need to set. The missing one is the interval parameter (the 3rd one). `AlarmManager` has constants declared for  intervals such as daily, half a day, and more.

If you want it repeating make sure you don't use `alarmManager.set()' and use`alarmManager.setRepeating`.

Additionally, if you want to give the user the option to have it repeat or not, you can make a simple bool check. If repeating, use `.setRepeating`, else use `.set`.

Edit: Not having used `.setRepeating()` myself, I'm not sure if it works how you want with the `.INTERVAL_DAY` constant. You may have to use `.setInexactRepeating()` instead. The parameters would look exactly the same:

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

[AlarmManager | Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: Let us know if it doesn't work. We may need to see more of your code if it doesn't, such as a snippet of the Class you're creating the `alarmManager` in.

Comment: alright i tried both of them and i tried it on my phone by changing the date to see if it works but it didn't, i downloaded an alarm manager example and modified it i think it has something to do with the date thing because when i change the date it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean when you change the date it doesn't work? Are you saying that if you don't change the date it **does** work?

Comment: actually i tried with changing the time only in the date and time settings and it didn't work either, i think it has something to do with if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){ //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); } in the code below

Comment: If you feel that the `if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0)` is the issue, you can comment out that block and test the code that way. However, I don't think it's the issue. Try removing/commenting out the `alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);` line immediately before `if(repeat)`. Also, if you set the alarm for a time in the past (like 5 minutes ago), the alarm should activate immediately. Then you don't need to change your system dates/times. If you had higher rep I'd start a chat.

Comment: well i think i found out the problem, i wanted it to go off at the set time without caring about the date so i removed 
Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance(); and 
if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                    //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                    calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); 
and then i tested it out and tried changing the date and moving back the time 1 minute before the set time and it worked but the sound didn't work the second time. thank you so much for your help and sorry for taking too much from your time.